# How to load images without making the page scroll?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm making a website, and there is a portion of the site where you can view packages and book packages. When you book the package, it will scroll down to a contact form and fills in whatever package you booked.

However, above the package section, there is a portfolio section of the website with a lot of images. The problem is that when you click on the link to book the package, the page will go the contact form, but the images in the portfolio will load and pull the viewport back up to the images because they are loading and thus taking the user away from the contact form...

I'll leave a link to a testing server so you could see what I'm talking about.

This is just a testing server, I'll change it later.

http://68.183.175.48/

**here is my css for the portfolio section**

```
#portfolio {
  min-height: 50vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.portfolio__image:hover {
  transition: .5s;
  filter: brightness(50%);
}
```

**here is my html. Again, I'm using ruby on rails, so this is ERB syntax**

```
<section id='portfolio'>
  <div class='container'>
    <h2 class='section-title mt-5'>Portfolio</h2>
    <div class='row no-gutters mb-5'>
      <% @homepage.images.each do |image| %>
        <div class='col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12'>
          <%= link_to image_tag(image, class: 'portfolio__image', width: '100%'), rails_blob_url(image), class: '' %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

From your link and Chrome browser I see no issue - the images are loaded above the form and the page doesn't move around as you describe.

I'm on a fast connection so I am assuming what you are describing is your images aren't yet loaded so the page space isn't yet allocated in the DOM - so as you move down to the form area the images then load and their dimensions push down the page/form meaning your images come into that area of the page the form occupied.

Perhaps one way to resolve this is to use a fixed height bounding box around the  gallery so it has a designated area even if the images aren't yet loaded?

Alternatively provide the image dimensions in the HTML so the DOM is aware of the space to reserve even when the image isnt yet loaded (this may be the best option)

Comment: wow, that's really interesting. I'm stilling getting that bug on my devices. I'm using Firefox on my development machine, and Safari on my iPhone. I'm getting the bug on both. Perhaps I'll try that bounding-box, but I'm not too sure how to do that. I'll post my CSS.

Comment: Or perhaps I could just handle it with javascript? Then I wouldn't really have to worry about links or anything. I'll try that out too, thanks for the fast response.

Comment: no problem. From scanning your html even the thumbnails are massive they are basically full sized images so in realtity you are loading all those full sized images even if no one clicks on them. Your page would load faster with actual thumbnails created to a smaller size therefore reducing that effect of images loading. Not sure javascript will help here certainly until the larger thumbnails are reduced

Comment: BTW using chrome developer tools network and performance I can see your page is loading 10mb of data because your thumbnails are anything from 100kb to half a mb. really they should be small thumbnails of around 10-20kb and the page will load a lot faster. Try setting smaller images but link to the larger image based on the user clicking the actualy image else every user downloads 10mb of files even if they dont look at a single image

Comment: Despite reducing the image size, the scrolling still occurs. If you would like to see it, I've updated the images. The images are now between 10-20kb. However, I would like to add a lightbox or slideshow for the images in the portfolio, which means they need to have a little bit higher of a resolution. But I digress. I reduced the size, and the scrolling still occurs. Any ideas?

Comment: Im getting timeouts on your testsite. The ability to have lightbox isnt dependent on the size of thumbnails - your anchor tag links to the larger quality image and the inner img tag references the thumbnail - previous you linked both to large images. Anyway have you added actual height & width to the HTML as that instructs  DOM to reserve space for the images. From memory you had set 100% width which doesnt really help your situation as theres no height property - you may have to fall back on a fixed height in PX on img or add fixed height to the div that wraps all the thumbnails.